# Showing an operation $\langle\bullet,\bullet\rangle$ is an inner product on $P_3(\Bbb C)$

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have an operation $\langle\bullet,\bullet\rangle$ that I need to show is an inner product on $P_3(\Bbb C)$.

For this, do I just do four proofs showing:

- A) Inner product of a vector with itself is not negative.
- B) Inner product is commutative.
- C) Inner product maintains distributivity over addition.
- D) Inner product of scalar * vector = scalar * inner product of vector.

Comment: The title is staring at me with wide, unblinking eyes. It's almost creepy.

Comment: $\langle\odot,\odot\rangle$

Comment: Woah, lets keep it clean @Stahl

Comment: $ \overbrace{ \left \langle \underbrace{\hat{\bullet},\hat{\bullet}} \right \rangle }$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axioms for an inner-product $\langle\bullet,\bullet\rangle$ on a complex vector space $V$ are

- Conjugate Symmetry: $v,w\in V\Rightarrow\langle v,w\rangle=\overline{\langle w,v\rangle}$
- Linearity: $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\Bbb C$ and $v_1,v_2,2\in V$ imply $$\langle\lambda_1 \cdot v_1+\lambda_2\cdot v_2,w\rangle=\lambda_1\cdot\langle v_1,w\rangle+\lambda_2\cdot\langle v_2,w\rangle$$
- Positive-Definiteness: $v\in V\Rightarrow\langle v,v\rangle\geq 0$  and $\langle v,v\rangle=0\Rightarrow v=\mathbf 0$

I think you have all of these except for the *conjugate* part of symmetry and the degeneracy condition.